# Selecting specific columns in many to many relationship with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to Models for two Entities in Database. Model `User` and Model `Role`. These two entities have a many-to-many relationship. In the model files I have class `User.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
                name = "role_user", 
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and I have class `Role.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    private String role;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)        
    private Set<User> users;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I also have the repositories/DAO for them:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{}
```

and

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {}
```

Now when I fetch all results from class `Role` it returns all the columns from Entity `User`, how can I specify that I want only the column `name` from `User` Entity? Should I build another model only with the columns I need or there is any simple way to select specific columns?

Comment: If you are returning them in a JSON format you could just add a @JsonIgnore above the column..

Comment: @mkane, I am not having that problem with @JsonIgnore, my problem is that I can see all the columns in class User so (id, username, password, and name) and in my case, I want to see only the column  `name` and not all of them

Comment: Oh OK that is why I was thinking just add @JsonIgnore to id, username and password..

Comment: @mkane, OK that is working! Is there any way that I can pass this as a parameter, sometimes I need the other columns.

Comment: I dont think you can pass it as a parameter but you could look into the @JsonSerialize annotation and pass it a custom Serializer , Inside that custom Serializer class you could add logic as to when to ignore and when not to ignore...